# uitableviewcell details

Tags: uitableview

I've got Audio class with 3 properties:
Artist, Titlle and Duration. As you can see (on screenshot) i've put 2 props succesfully.
How to put duration into UITableViewCell where i've written "Duration" if it's possible?

Timur

here is screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl8NP.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if (cell == nil) {  

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:...............



             UILabel *durationLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250,12 , 60,20 )];



             durationLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

             durationLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];


             durationLabel.tag=55;

             [cell.contentView addSubview:durationLabel];

             [durationLabel release];


     }


             UILabel *label=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:55];

             label.text = @"vijay";
```

Comment: Anyway i need to add new label? Are there label like cell.delailedLabel?

Comment: i did what you said, it works, but strange:)
when i select row, numbers are drawing strange, when i deselect row it shows good
here is screenshot http://s59.radikal.ru/i164/1108/67/068bf24c3a17.jpg
it begins when i scroll list up and down one time and select row

Comment: i've found problem, it's memory leak when i'm creating new uilabel. every scroll creates new uilabel despite created uilabel before that:)